# White Screen When Includding A Folder With PHP Files

Tags: plugins, php, include, fatal-error

So I'm currently working on a plugin using the boilerplate plugin structure. The problem comes up when I try to include a folder full of files that are needed for my project. I go to the admin class and I include everything from this folder using this code:

```
foreach(glob('folder/*.php' ) as $file) {
    include_once $file;
}
```

This produces an error when I create an instance of one of the classes I'm including. If I do not create instances, there is no error.

Though, if I use this code on the top of the file everything works as expected.

```
include_once('folder/class1.php');
include_once('folder/class2.php');
include_once('folder/class3.php');
include_once('folder/class4.php');
include_once('folder/class5.php');
```

Comment: So _which_ error does it produce? :) How is it specific to WP rather than general PHP mechanics?

Comment: In PHP i tested it and it works fine with 
foreach(glob('folder/*.php' ) as $file) {
    include_once $file;
}
 but Wordpress was not working some times, strange behavior.

Comment: So using the  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the WP coding guide, please, use WP Plugin API.
In your case place the following code into start of the main `.php` file of the plugin.

```
// Working directory definition.
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

// Attaching executable
require_once MY_PLUGIN_DIR . 'folder/class-my-class.php';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after using the constant it worked fine!

`define( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

foreach(glob(MY_PLUGIN_DIR . 'file/*.php' ) as $file) {
 include_once $file;
}`

Comment: Cool.
Else I recommend you use `require_once` directive. If some error will occur while loading a file , you won't know about this, because `include_once` simply generates a PHP Notice while `require_once` throws an Error.